# objective c button disabling queues user touch ups

Tags: objective-c

i'm writing an ap for which, when you press on the button, the button should be disabled for a random amount of time between 0-10seconds and after that, the button becomes active again. However, while the button is disabled, if the user clicks, the click seems to just be queued up waitingg for the button to be enabled and the click will be processed. how would i disable and not enqueue user clicks?

```
-(void)buttonPressed{
    NSLog(@"Button pressed!");
    button.userInteractionEnabled=false;
    sleep(rand()%10);
    progLabel.text=@"button is enabled!";
    button.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a button that derives from `UIControl` (`UIButton`?).  You can take advantage of its existing `enabled` property.  Setting the property to `NO` will ignore all touch events.  See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) for information regarding `UIControl`.

Also, another issue I see in your example is your `sleep()` function.  I'm not familiar with that function, but it *could* be blocking the main thread.  Be cautious.  Instead, you should use an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).  After each interval, you might do this:  `button.enabled = !button.enabled` for a toggle effect.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this in place of the sleep() func

```
[self performSelector:@selector(sleepMethood) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

in the methood call the sleep function

```
-(void) sleepMethood
{
sleep(rand()%10);
}
```

or another workaround would be

```
-(void)buttonPressed{
NSLog(@"Button pressed!");
button.alpha=0.7;
button.enabled=NO;
[self performSelector:@selector(BtnEnblMethood) withObject:nil afterDelay:(rand()%10)];
progLabel.text=@"button is enabled!";
}

-(BtnEnblMethood)
{ 
button.alpha=1;
button.enabled=YES;
}
```